# Adding AutoComplete behavior to a custom textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I am using a custom `TextBox` control in my `WinForm` app. It inherits from the `Control` class. It comes from a `.dll` so I cannot modify its code. I need this control to have the `AutoComplete` behavior the way normal TextBoxes do but this control unfortunately lacks them (`AutoCompleteMode`, `AutoCompleteSource` and `AutoCompleteCustomSource`). How can I extend the functionality of this control so that it also supports AutoComplete?

Comment: You can process `TextChanged` event manually to alter content. Not sure how you can show matching list though, but adding something at the end of currently entered text (which is selected by default and will be overwritten if user keeps typing) shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Sinatr isn't there a way to add AutoComplete properties behavior from the `TextBoxBase` class in a new custom Control?

Comment: It's impossible to *add base class*. There is no multi-inheritance in `C#`, so you can't create `MyTextBox` which will inherit from `TextBoxBase` and some custom `TextBox`.

Comment: You best bet is to either add it *on top* (extra functionality to pass user input to underlying custom `TextBox`) or use given by author functionality. My first comment assume there is `TextChanged` event and possibility to select text (similar to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983718.aspx)).